# Making a TD clickable and an INPUT inside NOT

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I have the following html which calls a jQuery function from the datatables plugin to sort the column upon clicking the table header cell:

```
<th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="jobBonusSummary" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 67px;" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column ascending">
<span class="filter_column filter_text">
<input type="text" rel="1" value="Name" class="text_filter search_init">
</span></th>
```

My th is clickable and I want to make either the span or the INPUT NOT clickable (whichever works!) Right now if I click into the INPUT for instance, it sorts the column when I want it to do nothing unless I click in the area around the INPUT.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Place your jquery code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since events bubble up in the dom tree, your click into the input field eventually reaches the surrounding th. You manually need to stop the propagation to prevent that.

```
$("input").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  // Here you can do additional stuff, which in your case might not be needed
});
```

[the jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)